# IOS: Writing EXIF to ImageData not Reflecting unless I append data to original EXIF Dictionary fetched from ImageData

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, exif

I am working on a camera app. I want to append DateTimeOriginal & DateTimeDigitized to the exif metadata. I have created Swift category Class for getting and saving Exif.

```
import ImageIO

extension NSData {

    func exifNSDict() -> NSDictionary? {
        return _exifCFDict() as NSDictionary?
    }

    func exifCFDict() -> CFDictionaryRef? {
        return _exifCFDict()
    }

    func imageNSUTI() -> NSString? {
        return _imageUTI() as NSString?
    }

    func imageCFUTI() -> CFStringRef? {
        return _imageUTI()
    }

    func appendExif(exif: CFDictionaryRef) -> NSData? {
        return _appendExif(exif)
    }
}

//MARK: - Private

extension NSData {

    private func _exifCFDict() -> CFDictionaryRef? {

        //1.(a) Create original image source ref
        let imageSource: CGImageSourceRef? =      CGImageSourceCreateWithData(self, nil)

        if imageSource == nil {
            return nil
        }

        //1.(b) Get image properties
        let imageProperties: CFDictionaryRef? = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil)

        if imageProperties == nil {
            return nil
        }

        //1.(b) Get original exif
        let dictKey = unsafeBitCast(kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, UnsafePointer<Void>.self)
        let exif: CFDictionaryRef? = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, dictKey), CFDictionaryRef.self)

        if exif == nil {
            return nil
        }

        return exif
    }

    private func _imageUTI() -> CFStringRef? {

        let imageSource: CGImageSourceRef? = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(self, nil)

        if imageSource == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let imageUTI: CFStringRef? = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource!)

        return imageUTI
    }

    private func _appendExif(exif: CFDictionaryRef) -> NSData? {

        //writing both original image data and mutable exif back to a destination
        let imageSource: CGImageSourceRef? = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(self, nil)

        if imageSource == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let imageUTI: CFStringRef? = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource!)

        if imageUTI == nil {
            return nil
        }

        //3. create a mutable data object to which the originalImageData and exif dictionary will be written.
        let finalCombinedData = NSMutableData()

        //4. create a destination object where the whole thing needs to be written
        let destination : CGImageDestinationRef? = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(finalCombinedData, imageUTI!, 1, nil)

        if destination == nil {
            return nil
        }

        //5. This is the actual method that does the writing.
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination!, imageSource!, 0, exif);

        //6. Commit the writing
        let success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination!);

        if !success {//error
            return nil
        }

        return finalCombinedData.copy() as? NSData
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get exif by calling exifCFDict

```
CFDictionaryRef exif = [imageData exifCFDict];
```

I then created a MutableCFDictionaryRef from this CFDictionaryRef, and appended values for kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal and kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized as follows:

```
1.(b) Convert original exif to mutable exif                                                            
CFMutableDictionaryRef mutableExif = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, exif);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                                         [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *nowDateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
CFDictionarySetValue(mutableExif, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal, (__bridge const void *)nowDateStr);
CFDictionarySetValue(mutableExif, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized, (__bridge const void *)nowDateStr);
```

I can see kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal and kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized in the mutable copy.
I then tried to write this mutable dictionary to the imageData by calling the appendExif function in above category.

```
//append exif to originalImageData
NSData *imageDataWithExif = [imageData appendExif:mutableExif];
```

However, when I tried to get exif from imageDataWithExif, I realized that kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal & kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized are missing. All other info is present.

After some hit and tries, I found a workaround. If instead of creating a mutable copy for exif, I just appended kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized & kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal to original Exif fetched from Image Data and then if I pass this original exif to appendExif function, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal and kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized are present in the new imageData.

```
CFDictionarySetValue(exif, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal, (__bridge const void *)nowDateStr);
CFDictionarySetValue(exif, kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized, (__bridge const void *)nowDateStr);

//append exif to originalImageData
NSData *imageDataWithExif = [imageData exif];
```

This has solved my problem for now, but this workaround has left me baffled.

- How am I able to append key values to a CFDictionaryRef?
- Why is it that unless I pass the original exif dictionary object that is obtained from the image data, my changes to the dictionary are getting ignored.

P.S. I am fairly new to IOS development.